# Asyncronous, two awaitable methods. Only one returns

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Im having some problem with asyncronous programming.

If you look at this example:

```
public async void SaveUsersThings(List<User> Users )
{                      
    await SaveUsersCars(Users);
    await SaveUsersHouses(Users);          
}
```

So I expect `SaveUsersThings` to perform the two following methods:

```
public async Task SaveUsersCars(List<User> Users)
{
    var listofCars = new List<Car>();
    foreach (var item in Users)
    {
        var cars = await _sqlrepo.GetAllCars(item.UserId);
        foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            listofCars.Add(car);
        }
    }

    _sqlrepo.SaveListOfCars(listofCars);
}
```

And then this (identical  as the above except for the obj)

```
public async Task SaveUsersHouses(List<User> Users)
{
    var listofHouses = new List<House>();
    foreach (var item in Users)
    {
        var houses = await _sqlrepo.GetAllHouses(item.UserId);
        foreach (var house in houses)
        {
            listofHouses.Add(house);
        }
    }
    _sqlrepo.SaveListOfHouses(listofHouses);
}
```

The problem is that only the first method completes what it is supposed to do (save some things to the db). I guess It has to do with me not fully understanding this kind of programming. Can someone explain how I can get both methods to "work"?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried debugging? We can't help with the provided information. Maybe bug with `_sqlrepo.SaveListOfHouses` implementation? Debug your code and find where does it goes wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the first is throwing an exception. Your code will exercise the two tasks in sequence.

Comment: What... on earth... are you doing in that method?  I hope you edited out the code where you do *something* to the list of objects after you get them and before you write them back to the database.  Because, damn son.

Comment: Haha, yes =) I have edited out most of the code that does something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public async void SaveUsersThings(List<User> Users )
```

How can you know if there's an error?  `async void` effectively ignores any errors.  (I suspect that the C# team really didn't want to support `async void` at all, but needed to for backward compatibility with some existing paradigms.  Something about event handlers, I don't know.)  Basically the `void` prevents any consuming code from actually awaiting the result or examining that result.  So there could very well be an `AggregateException` which simply has nowhere to go.

`async` should be ["async all the way down"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).  Make the top-level method awaitable:

```
public async Task SaveUsersThings(List<User> Users )
```

This way whatever invokes `SaveUsersThings()` can await it and examine the result.  It may not guarantee that "both methods will work", but it does at least expose the *reason* that something isn't working.  Instead of guessing.

Comment: `async void` methods will take the process down. Isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I'm not sure what you're asking.  To my knowledge, `async void` simply isn't awaitable or examinable because it doesn't return a `Task`.  So it's effectively a "fire and forget" pattern.  And the problem with "fire and forget" becomes clear when there's an error, since the code by design can't report that error.  `async void` *can* be used, but any asynchronous code therein should be handled *very carefully* and with a strong understanding of synchronization contexts.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, unobserved task exceptions will no longer take a process down, [this is a change to .net in 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx) To get the old behavior back you need to put `<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
</configuration>` in your app.config.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think this has something to do with `SynchronizationContext`. In console apps `async void` method will crash your process. Let me come with an example.

Comment: @user2915962 don't put code in commetns. Update your question with the new information.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I was incorrect. I was thinking of what happens when you return a `Task` but then never await it. `async void` exceptions still bring down the app in both console and wpf (just tested)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think I was slow. [here is the snippet](https://gist.github.com/SriramSakthivel/16830879923f27c61883) for future readers and OP of the answer

Comment: Try to run the above script in a console application. process will crash after 2 seconds. Async void is fire and forget but if unhandled exception occur inside of it, no excuses; your process will be taken down. So first paragraph of this answer is misleading. Consider changing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the link. Im gonna read up!